# Need substitute for a diode now obsolete

Tags: diodes

As a beginner I simply don't know enough to deal with this alone. I am repairing a power supply for a Soundcraft sound mixer. The EPM12. The blown diode shows GP10GE. Additionally it has another row showing 0541A. I believe it to be a switching rectifier. If it at all helps, it's D4 on the board.

Comment: what's the point of saying that it is labeled D4?

Answer (score 2):

When you look for components with part number GP10GE, you find a myriad of diodes with various suffixes and permutations of the part number. These are largely to distinguish them from one manufacturer to another, but are all nearly the same part. (I didn't find any diodes labeled 0541A; an image showing what you are working on would have been helpful.)

The properties you want to match with a diode like this are:

- Reverse voltage (400 V)
- Average rectified current (1 A)
- Forward voltage (1.1 V)
- Package size (through hole, DO-204 or DO-41)

For example, there is a [GP10G-E3/54](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88637/gp10a.pdf) made by Vishay which appears to be the same as the base part number, and is still active according to a few vendors I checked.

Some properties should be matched while others can be exceeded. For example, a diode that can withstand a higher reverse voltage such as 500 V would be acceptable. The forward voltage, however, may be something that needs to match or possibly lower, depending on the circuit it is from.

Comment: Might reverse recovery time also be relevant for a switching power supply? (Really it depends what the diode is used for. There could be a reason they chose this less common glass one instead of a 1N4004, or maybe it was just the cheapest when they built the mixer)

Comment: @user253751 Yes, there are some other important properties to look at as well. In this case, every 400 V 1 A through-hole rectifier I found had a faster recovery time (3 µs was the slowest) so I left it out to keep it simple.

Comment: hm for some reason I had thought the 1N4004 had a much slower recovery time

Comment: Thank you! That was my novice conclusion.